# Error while publishing the workflow in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Currently, I've configured workflow manager in sharepoint server 2013 for using shareoint 2013 workflow in designer. But, while publishing the workflow, it shows following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation failed with error
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowCommunicationException: The request
>   was aborted: The request was canceled

[image]

I had registered the workflow service using:

> Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite 'http://sharepoint.example.com'
>   -WorkflowHostUri `http://workflowhost:23302` -AllowOAuthHttp -Force

So, what can be the solution? Is it out of memory problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue gets resolved after installing [Cumulative Update for Service Bus 1.0 (KB2799752)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36794) and [Cumulative Update for Workflow Manager 1.0 (KB2799754)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36800)

Answer (score 0):

The last answer did not solve my issue. It triggered error when I ran the KB

Rebooting did solve the problem